# format month of grouped news items in Typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have news items, grouped by year and month. Here the code:

```
<f:groupedFor each="{paginatedNews}" as="groupedNews1" groupBy="yearOfDatetime" groupKey="year">
                        <f:groupedFor each="{groupedNews1}" as="groupedNews" groupBy="monthOfDatetime" groupKey="month">
                            <div style="border:1px solid blue;padding:10px;margin:10px;">
                                    <h1>{month} {year} </h1>
                                    <f:for each="{groupedNews}" as="newsItem">
                                            <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem,settings:settings,iterator:iterator}" />
                                    </f:for>
                            </div>
                        </f:groupedFor>
                    </f:groupedFor>
```

Unfortunately, month and year are displayed in numbers in frontend, e.g.

```
03 2019
..(some news items)
02 2019
...
01 2019
```

However, what I need is this:

```
March 2019
...
February 2019
...
January 2019
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the original EXT:news this method has been used:

Look at the template EXT:news/Resources/Private/Templates/News/DateMenu.html

```
<f:translate key="month.{month}" />
```

on the EXT:news/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf you will find:

```
    <trans-unit id="month.01" xml:space="preserve">
            <source>January</source>
    </trans-unit>
```

And so forth.